# PDF display issue in iFrame once upload using Paperclips in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, iframe

I am working on `Rails application` where uploaded `PDF` using `Paperclip Gem`. Now try to `display PDF` using below HTML code.

> > Upload PDF settings

```
has_attached_file :agreement
validates_attachment_content_type :agreement, :content_type =>["application/pdf"]

<iframe src="/system/contracts/agreements/000/000/022/original/pdf_ag.pdf" align="middle" style="width: 100%; height:720px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

> > But got error below

```
error : ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template sessions/unknown_route, application/unknown_route

No route matches [GET] "/system/contracts/agreements/000/000/022/original/pdf_ag.pdf"
```

I tried but same issue again and again. Let me know if any one have idea or trick.

Thanks

Comment: Please share more details like your controller and form.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, static content path, for regular Rails app, starts with `/public` so `/public/system/contracts/agreements/` and so on..

Make sure that your app, in the specific env where you're getting the error, handles static files (`config.serve_static_assets = true` for Rails < 5 and `config.public_file_server.enabled = true` for Rails >= 5).

Also I'd advise to use absolute path instead of relative. It offers you more flexibility in case you decide to delegate your static files to nginx or CDN server OR you're requesting this PDF from iFrame on the domain different that current app.

Answer (score 0):

I store `PDF files` in `public folder` and access it. It's work for me.

Thanks for your supports.